# Understanding Bash pipes

Tags: bash, svn

I have a directory of SVN repositories at work. I'd like to pull a log from each of them and dump it to a file for sending out daily activity updates and other misc polls.

I'm just learning `bash`, and it sounds like a pipe is what I would want to feed in a list of directories to `svnlook log`. But, my inuition fails me, when I tried something to the tune of `ls -d */ | svnlook log`, I just get `svnlook: E000002: Can't open file '$/format': No such file or directory`.

I've been digging around on google for a good 20 minutes and I can't find the syntax I need.

Comment: You are running that on the actual repositories themselves? Quick looking online makes it seem like `svnlook log` expects an argument of the path and not to read from standard input. If that's the case then you need to use `xargs` or a manual loop over the file names. Also [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Yes, this is a simple script to be run on the `vault` directory on our server which contains all the repos. Thank you, I will look into `xargs` and see if I can implement that as you said.

Comment: Also `cd $reposdir; for i in *; do svnlook "$i"; done > Log`

Comment: That `for` loop did the trick very nicely. I added an `echo` line to make a header and format each entry. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please add the solution as an answer and mark it as 'accepted' so that people who stumble across this question can benefit.